# I am looking for a company that I can invest in-ex;Buy shares - That is nearly 100% halal

Tags: fiqh, business, investment

A company that does not involve in Riba transactions. Is there such a company?

ISlam q and A has been useless with providing examples of such companies...

Perhaps some here knows...

Thank you,
Salaam Alaykum

Comment: How do you understand Riba to begin with?  There are many companies that do not lend on a interest fee.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically a very hard question to answer, because it is not dealt with in the Islamic tradition so anything you can read would be some mufti saying something that may or may not contradict another mufti.

In [this link](http://www.darulihsan.com/index.php/q-a/fatwa-q-a/business/item/3407-share-trading-in-islam) for example, they give figures such that

> "the total debt of the company should not exceed 45% of the total
>   asset"

or

> "total income from haraam sources should not exceed 5% of the total
>   income. Further the total investments of the company in non-Sharia
>   compliant activities should not be more than 33% of the total assets
>   of the company."

I don't know how they arrived at these figures, you may want to look for opposite views before you make your choice.

If you want to find islamic compliant businesses to invest in, try searching for what is called "[Islam index](http://thomsonreuters.com/en/products-services/financial/islamic-finance/islamic-indices.html)".

There are many such companies (there are 4 in the [London Stock Exchange](http://www.londonstockexchange.com/specialist-issuers/islamic/finance.htm) for example). I would consider all these "nearly" halal so I will not influence your choice further.